# How join statements execute in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to fetch the data from user table such that every row contains date value(not null). If value is null then it should be view that column with a date of id of above date which have same id.
Without updating the table rows, only with select statement?

Here is the table

```
NAME, DATE, ID
A, 2021-01-21, 1
B, null, 1
C, null, 1
D, 2021-01-18, 2
D, null, 2
```

It should be viewed like

```
A, 2021-01-21, 1
B, 2021-01-21, 1
C, 2021-01-21, 1
D, 2021-01-18, 2
D, 2021-01-18, 2
```

Now the query I think is =>

```
select t1.name, t2.date ,t1.id from user t1 
left join (select id ,date from user where id=1) t2 
on t1.id=t2.id;
```

But this query doesn't work like I thought.

Can anyone please tell me how above join query works ? And how can I improve it ? So that I got the required result.

For testing of above query use this queries =>

```
create table user(
 name varchar(20),
 date date,
 id integer
);
insert into user values("A",'2021-01-21',1);
insert into user values("",null,1);
insert into user values("",null,1);
insert into user values("",null,1);
insert into user values("",null,1);
insert into user values("",null,1);
insert into user values("B",'2021-01-20',2);

select t1.name, t2.date ,t1.id from user t1 
left join (select id ,date from user where id=1) t2 
on t1.id=t2.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you are joining a table with itself on the condition `t1.id = t2.id`. So if you have 4 rows with `id=1` and 3 rows with `id=2` just as an example, you will end up with a result that had 4 * 4 + 3 * 3 = 25 rows. In your specific case you will end up with 6 * 6 + 1 * 1 = 37 rows.

The second problem is that you have hard-code selecting `id=1` in your subquery:

```sql
(select id ,date from user where id=1) t2
```

This can't be the appropriate value for all possible rows.

You *could* try the obvious:

```sql
select
   t1.name,
   ifnull(t1.date, (select t2.date from user t2 where t2.date is not null and t2.id = t1.id limit 1)) as date,
   t1.id
from user t1
;
```

[see db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2PVdTjZNtErsy6h33qRQat/1)

| name | id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2021-01-21 |
|  | 1 | 2021-01-21 |
|  | 1 | 2021-01-21 |
|  | 1 | 2021-01-21 |
|  | 1 | 2021-01-21 |
|  | 1 | 2021-01-21 |
| B | 2 | 2021-01-20 |

---

But better would be to use a join:

```sql
select u.name, ifnull(u.date, sq.date) as date, u.id
from user u join (
    select id, min(date) as date from user group by id
) sq on u.id = sq.id
;
```

[see db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2PVdTjZNtErsy6h33qRQat/2)

**I would expect the second version using a join to be more efficient because the first version has a dependent subquery that has to get executed for every row that has a null date.**

Comment: thanks for the query. Can you please explain me my join statement behaviour that how does it works here ?

Comment: I've added a second, more efficient query that uses a join -- but not in the same way as yours.

Comment: Can you explain me that how 4 rows with id=1 and 3 rows with id=2 will end up with a result that had 4 * 4 + 3 * 3 = 25 rows. I mean how internally join execute it ?

Comment: @Rajatkashyap I think at this point you need to look at a tutorial on joins, which could do a far better job of explaining it than I could. But *each* row from the first table with id=1 is combined with *each* row from the second table with id=1 and that's how you get 4 * 4 = 16 rows just from rows with id=1.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `join`.  Just use a window function:

```
select name,
       max(date) over (partition by id) as date,
       id
from users;
```

Note that your sample data doesn't match the data in the question.  That data suggests:

```
select max(name) over (partition by id) as name,
       max(date) over (partition by id) as date,
       id
from user;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ece8231f8d98989dbcd734d9043685ec) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Your answer would, of course, depend on the version of MySQL the OP is using. It seems to me that when people post a question tagged with `mysql`, the guidelines should state that they should also specify what version they are operating under.

Comment: @Booboo . . . This does require MySQL 8+, which was released over three years ago.

Comment: Right, and my ISP (supposedly the leader) is still on 5.7.